# How to dismantle a product in Odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

So if we get a product for example for "Dell PC with 4GB ram" but the customer wants "16GB"

how to dismantle or divide the Dell PC into "Dell PC without ram" and "4GB ram"

then use the "Dell PC without ram" + "16GBram"

and the "4GB ram" should be added to the stock

input(Dell PC with 4GBram) + 16GBram = output(Dell PC with 16GBram) 4GBram in stock

OPT_check

- **(Product Variants)** can't sell 4GBram separately also implies that is I have in stock a "Dell PC with 4GBram" and a "Dell PC with 16GBram". *@AdamStrauss*
- **(Negative Quantities)** -- **HOW** set "Dell PC with 4GBram" to (-1), set "4GBram" to (+1) and "Dell PC without ram" (+1) then sell "Dell PC without ram" + "16GBram". *@CharifDZ*

Comment: You should work with product variants

Comment: product variants would allow me to sell either but not add the removed "4GB ram" to stock/Inventory

Comment: input(Dell PC with 4GBram + 16GBram) = output(Dell PC with 16GBram) 4GBram in stock

Comment: Then I think create Dell system with different Ram variants too

Comment: but by using product variants you will not be able to sell 4GBram in stock  separately

Comment: product variants also mean that is I have in stock a "Dell PC with 4GBram" and a "Dell PC with 16GBram"@AdamStrauss

Comment: Yeah got it....

Comment: So why don't you just create another product DELL that don't have any variants and I think you all ready have a product RAM (variant 4G), adjust these quantities :  DELL 4G (-1) , product 4G RAM (+1)  and product DELL (+1). and sell these two product new Product DELL + RAM 16GB. or instead of creating a new product add value to variant 0GB to indicate that this product the RAM was removed.

Comment: How to give negative quantities @CharifDZ

Comment: Not negative If you have 10 do an inventory for the product and make it 9. And explain why you did that

Comment: If I understood well you would need some manufacture workflow. Take a look at how the bills of materials (BOM) work

Comment: In odoo manufacturing by default you can add “dell 4gb” + “16gb ram” to make new items “dell 16gb” but without being able to get “4gb ram” as an extra output. so what i am asking is how to make it add one to the “4gb ram” at the end of the manufacturing process.@CharifDZ @ChesuCR

Comment: You should divide you product into sub products. You can create Computer Product and you could create accessories which is also product. Then you link the Computer to it's accessories so If someone bought computer you should auto populate accessories in the Order so if someone wanted to change the accessory then you replace the product with another accessory and if someone want to buy only the accessory then you could sell it by itself and your stock will be deducted.

Comment: @ChesuCR that is what I was talking about but a (BOM) gets Bill of material combine them, The problem would be adding “X” number to the 4GBRAM at the end